# CallableStatement vs Statement

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc

When calling a Stored Procedure with no arguments and no output is there any advantage to using a [CallableStatement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) over a regular [Statement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) or [PreparedStatement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CallableStatement` allows you to use a generic JDBC syntax for calling procedures rather than a Database specific one.

Sadly, we didn't do that for Oracle in one of the projects I've worked on, so all our procedure calls look something like this:

```
String query = "begin package.sp_Procedure(?, ?); end;";
```