# what is the difference between Callable statement and Prepared Statement in Sql?

Tags: sql, prepared-statement, callable

Can anyone please explain the difference between Callable and Prepared Statement in Sql with any example?

Comment: Callable statement is used for executing Stored Procedures, not queries.

Comment: Look into this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371053/jdbc-statement-preparedstatement-callablestatement-and-caching/46975031#46975031) to get a detailed view of the Interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

At the top level you can go by this thought
Prepared Statement

Instances of PreparedStatement contain an SQL statement that has already been compiled. This is what makes a statement "prepared"

Because PreparedStatement objects are precompiled, their execution can be faster than that of Statement objects.

The prepared statement is used to execute sql queries
Callable Statement

A CallableStatement object provides a way to call stored procedures in a standard way for all RDBMSs. A stored procedure is stored in a database; the call to the stored procedure is what a CallableStatement object contains.